# Android listSelector doesnt work

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to style the List view and the list item as followings

**List View**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/color_dark_orange"
    android:divider="#fce082"
    android:dividerHeight="1px" />
```

**List Item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroud"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_holder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" >
        </ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_timestamp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Harsha Mallikarjun Vantagudi"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="2 hours"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xxsmall" >
                </TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Bangalore, India Bangalore, India Bangalore, India Bangalore, India"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

On pressing any List Item the color doesnt change.

***EDITED***

List View

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#fce082"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:listSelector="@color/color_dark_orange"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cache color hint is an RGB color set by default to the window's background 
color, that is #191919 in Android's dark theme. since the default cache color hint is #191919, you get a dark background behind each item during a scroll.To fix this issue, all you have to do is either disable the cache color hint optimization, if you use a non-solid color background, or set the hint to the appropriate solid color value. You can do this from code (see setCacheColorHint(int)) or preferably from XML, by using the android:cacheColorHint attribute. To disable the optimization, simply use the transparent color #00000000. :

**if you need to change the list item color while  pressing any List Item you have to add**

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/listselector"
```

**listselector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:constantSize="true">

  <item  android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">   
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

   <item  android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/listitemfocus"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/listitempress"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: thanks i have updated my code with screenshots. the whole bg changed to the select color now

Comment: Thanks Jennifer. i used an XML to fetch the BG based of the button state and it works. i dont even need listColor now ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be using `android:listSelector` attribute instead of `android:cacheColorHint`.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, using a color in your listSelector applies that color to the full list. However, if you create a shape resource with its solid attribute set to your color and use that drawable in the listSelector, it will behave as expected.

Here's my example (which references the colors I was originally trying to use):

red_faint_back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red_faint" />
</shape>
```

black_back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

and the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/black_back" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_faint_back" />
</selector>
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I set the lisselector in the coustom adapter instead of setting in the xml file , and it work ok.